# Dart: how to apply function to each inner element of list of lists

Tags: dart

Obviously playing with dart and still new to it and implementing tic tac toe. So I have a list of lists of winning positions and want to check if any of the lists is sublist of the inputed moves list. Sounds pretty easy right, so I apply for each element of inner list I wanna check my condition. What are the dart ways to achieve this. This isn't working because map expect function of type void and I return some calls to print for each element of every inner list obviously. Why it isn't showing me any mistake at all.

I tried with .forEach and .takeWhile examples but coudn't get it working.

```
List <List<int>> winMoves = new List.generate(8, (i) => new List(3));
winMoves[0]=[1,2,3];
winMoves[1]=[4,5,6];
winMoves[2]=[7,8,9];
winMoves[3]=[1,4,7];
winMoves[4]=[2,5,8];
winMoves[5]=[3,6,9];
winMoves[6]=[1,5,9];
winMoves[7]=[3,5,7];
winMoves.map((list) => (list.forEach((el) => print(el))));
```

Comment: What do you actually want do do instead of `print(el)`? Do you want to check if `winMoves` contains `[1,5,9]`? Is the order relevant or would `[5,9,1]` also match?

Comment: I have a list of moves [5,7,8,1,9] for example. I wanna check if [5,7,8,1,9] contains each element form [5,9,1].

Comment: For this example you can use `winMoves.indexWhere((list) => [5, 9, 1].every((val) => list.contains(val)))`

Comment: You mean something like winMoves.indexWhere((list) =>list.every((val) =>player1.contains(val))); //Player1 is [5,7,8,1,9]. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks right, yes.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart' show ListEquality;

...

const eq = const ListEquality<int>();
print(winMoves.indexWhere((list) => eq.equals(list, [1, 5, 9])));
```

Depending on what result you want you can also use `where`, `firstWhere`, `any`, ...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this problem, depending on what the exact desired result is.

You have a list of elements, and you want to check something about these elements (in this case the elements are lists too, but that's not important to begin with).

If you want to know whether any of the elements satisfies your check, you can use:

```
bool hasWin = winMoves.any((moves) => ...check...);
```

If you want to find an element which satisfies your check, you can use:

```
var win = winMoves.firstWhere((moves) => ...check..., orElse: null);
```

If you want to find *all* the winners:

```
var wins = winMoves.where((moves) => ...check...).toList();  // `where` is lazy.
```

How to write the check is a separate issue. In this case you seem to want, as Günther Zöchbauer has already written, something like

```
(moves) => moves.every(expectedMoves.contains)
```

Your example is not giving you any warnings or errors because it's correct, and it doesn't actually do anything. The `map` function is lazy, it creates an `Iterable` which won't do anything until you start iterating. If you call `.toList()` on it, it'll create a `List<void>`. Not very useful, but valid in Dart 2.

Also, your initial `winMoves` initialization is overly complex. You can just do:

```
List<List<int>> winMoves = []..length = 8;  // for growable list, or
List<List<int>> winMoves = List(8);         // for fixed-length list.
```

You actively fill the list with lists, then immediately overwrite those values with new lists in the following lines.